# Codeigniter $this->form_validation->run() always return false?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm sorry to ask again, I already check answered questions about this but I really can't solve this problem. Any help please. Thank you!

Autoload: `$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');`

View:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('members/update_password_validation/'.$id, array('role' => 'form'));

    echo validation_errors();

    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo form_label('Password:', 'password');
    echo form_password(array('name' => 'password', 'id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control'));
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo form_label('Confirm Password:', 'cpassword');
    echo form_password(array('name' => 'cpassword', 'id' => 'cpassword', 'class' => 'form-control'));
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo form_submit(array('name' => 'update_password_submit', 'value' => 'Update Password', 'class' => 'btn btn-default'));
    echo '</div>';

    echo form_close();
?>
```

Controller:

```
class Members extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        //some code here
    }

    public function update_password_validation($id)
    {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                    //success
            }
            else
            {
                    //fail
            }
    }
}
```

Why does `$this->form_validation->run()` always return false?

Comment: try `echo validation_errors(); die;` in else part for debugging

Comment: also for debugging: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';` in your controller: see if the form posts what you expect it to.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
                //success
        }
        else
        {
                //fail
        }
```